# Android Toolbar action Icons not completely white

Tags: android

I'm not sure why this is happening. When I have icons on the toolbar even though the resource files are completely white when they're added to the toolbar they seem to have some kind of slight transparency or they're just not white?

The icon on the right is how it looks on a device but the left is the resource image.

[Toolbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnB1a.png)

Code just in case I've done something wrong:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detailToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

---

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</style>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_white"
        android:title="Save Details"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

---

EDIT: Just in case someone else needs an answer to this question.

I was importing icons into Android studio via right click > New > Image Asset into my drawables folder, this seemed to be the issue.

Instead I copy and pasted the icon images into the drawables folder and then the icons reflected the true color.

Comment: Try this: add these local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" lines to toolbar and check once.

Comment: This changed my up navigation arrow to be white but the save icon just remained the same color sadly.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @Andrea - Yes if you read my edit above...my solution was that I needed to copy the image from the file directory and paste it directly into the drawables folder in Android studio

Answer (score 0):

edit this

```
   <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

  </style>
```